# Food Pre-Packaged in Vacuum Bags

Tags: vacuum, botulism

I often purchase chicken and fish that have been vacuum packed at the factory. Is the food, never having been exposed to air, susceptible to botulism or other anaerobic organisms? Is it best to sous vide these in their frozen state?

Comment: The flaw in your thinking is that the foods have been exposed to air and any other contaminants they may have come into contact with before they were packaged. So, any pesky bugs they came into contact with have been packaged with them.

Comment: By the way - Welcome to Seasoned Advice!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't advice either one.

If you sous vide from frozen, your cooking times are going to be off.  You might end up with it undercooked in the middle unless you significantly increase the cooking time.

And I've only done it in the packaging once.  Never again, as there was little to no flavor to it.  (no browning, no seasoning).  The only time that I might be willing to re-try it would be if I went to the partially-prepared section, and got the ones with marinade already in the bag.

Comment: I don't have a response to the original question, but, while you do need to adjust cooking time, sous vide from frozen is common and safe practice (as is cooking pre-packaged proteins).